# How to remove local admins from machines in a list

Tags: powershell, vbscript

Each week I receive a list of computers and one username associated with each computer.  I need to remove each particular user from the Administrators group on the associated computer.

Is there a way to script this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot fully test this, but you should be able to do essentially this:

Import the list:

```
Import-Csv "File.csv" | Foreach-Object {    
 $User= $_.Username    
 $PC = $_.ComputerName

 psexec "$PC" net user "$User" /delete 
}
```

This assumes you have header columns named Username and ComputerName.

Comment: You need underscores in $_.Username and $_.ComputerName, and a semicolon between them. Or better yet skip both those, get rid of the double quotes in your psexec line, and call $_.username and $_.computername directly there.

Comment: PowerShell you do not need a semi colon... And yes the $_.UserName is correct. And yes you *could* use $_.Username directly, I fail to see it as actually better in a script

Comment: The way you had it written originally was defining both `$User` and `$PC` on the same line without a semicolon. That would not have worked, and would have either needed a semicolon between them to imply a new line, or (as you have done) move the `$PC =` command to its own line.

Comment: Gotcha, @TheMadTechnician I didn't realie I goofed the format on posting and it looks like someone partially updated the script before I re-edited it the rest of the way.

Comment: That looks spot on, and should run just fine. It's up to you if you want to define `$User` and `$PC`, but if the list is long that's just extra overhead that can be avoided in general. I'll be adding an answer shortly that makes ADSI calls that may speed things up in general, but your answer should be perfectly function.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comment on his answer Austin French's answer should work just fine, though it may be kind of slow since it relies on an expternal application (PSExec) to make the connection to the remote computers, perform the actions, and then report back to PowerShell. Also expect some nasty errors because PSExec doesn't exactly play nice with PowerShell.

As an alternative I would suggest using the ADSI Type Adapter `[ADSI]` to perform the actions through .Net functionality.

```
$List = Import-CSV File.CSV 
ForEach($Item in $List){
    $objUser = [ADSI]("WinNT://domain/$($Item.UserName)")
    $objGroup = [ADSI]("WinNT://$($Item.ComputerName)/Administrators")
    $objGroup.PSBase.Invoke("Remove",$objUser.PSBase.Path)
}
```

That should work just fine. Obviously you need to put your domain name in where it says domain, or if the user to be removed is a local user account you would change that to $($Item.computername) instead. This would, I am fairly certain, work much faster than PSExec and not rely on an external application.